# Firebase UI authentication with google fails with message (code:10 message:10)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I've made a chat app that uses Firebase's feature `Real-time database`.
I face a problem with google authentication. The problem started when I downloaded the app from the Play Store, the authentication was working perfectly when I was running the app in debug mode. When users try to sign in they get a toast message `code:10 message:10`.

I would like to note here that: I've added the SHA1 fingerprint. How can I solve this?

*Not sure if this is helpful but I've followed step by step this [tutorial](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud0352)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need three keys in order to make it work:

1. The debug key. Informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144629/how-to-add-sha-1-to-android-application).
2. The release key. Informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38297493/get-android-release-certificate-fingerprints).
3. Google Play App signing key. Informations [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423).

All these keys are needed in order to make the sign-in process work.

Other informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347349/sha-certificate-firebase-debug-release).

Comment: I found this answer in another post in stackOverflow but as I am a beginner I don't know how to get all these keys! Can you edit your answer and elaborate it a little bit :) ?

Comment: I've added a debug and release SHA1 fingerprint but I don't understand how to add the third key ( google play app signing  key) .

Comment: That is the official documentation but please take also a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing).

Comment: Thank you a lot, actually it wasn't that hard to find that google play app key.
Now the google authentication works perfectly fine :)

Comment: @AlexMamo where to put the app signing key and what should be my default_web_client_id (within requestIdToken params), Pls check my issue on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861698/firebase-google-signin-error-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10. its really urgent

Comment: @ShikharJaiswal You should add the debug and release key in your Firebase console.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've added debug key into my firebase app, (by generating the signing report)...Pls tell more about release key and  where to add it, i followed the above link and when I run the command ($ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
) i get the same key as SHA1 generared throug signing report previously

Comment: @ShikharJaiswal See here on SO more [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firebase+release+key).

Comment: @AlexMamo Please help me out. I've already researched a ton of questions for the past  2 days, but Im completely stuck here and my release date is near. Pls help

Comment: Should we remove the debug key from Firebase after we hit production since everyone could have the same key?

Comment: @jackz314 It's up to you to decide that.

Comment: I've done all this and still getting the same error. What could I also check?

Comment: A fourth key will be needed if you intend on using internal app sharing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62763633/1702810

Answer (score 17):

After generating SHA1 for release key, I forgot downloading the new google-service.json file that caused the same error.

Make sure you follow the instruction https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth to generate and add debug/release SHA1 to firebase console and download google-service.json after updated.

If you use [Use app signing by Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB) option, you need an additional step:

After uploading app into google play console, go to Release management > App signing, copy SHA1 and paste to firebase console
[image]

**Update**

In the new google play console, the App signing key can be found as following:
Setup > App signing
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have added signed SHA1. If you are using debug one then it will not gonna work for live apk.

You need to put "debug.keystore" in this path C:\Users\USER_FOLDER_NAME.android

then in Android studio follow the below steps 
 1. Run your project 
 2. Click on Gradle menu 
 3. Expand Gradle Tasks tree 
 4. Double click on android -> signingReport

You can see SHA in Run Tab

for more information see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate)

Comment: Okay, how can I obtain a signed SHA1?

Comment: You need to put "debug.keystore" in this path `C:\Users\USER_FOLDER_NAME\.android`

then in Android studio 
follow the below steps

1. Run your project
2. Click on Gradle menu
3. Expand Gradle Tasks tree
4. Double click on android -> signingReport 
You can see SHA in Run Tab

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos please check the answer, I have updated it.

Comment: I have added this SHA1 fingerprint in firebase console and I am waiting to see if it is working :) Thank you for the help, I will keep you updated

Comment: I fixed it. Apart from adding the SHA1 key that you have told me about, we also need to add the Google Play App signing key as Alex Mamo said.

Comment: @Kwnstantinos Nikoloutsos where did you put the app signing key?

Comment: It is important that Gradle can give you not only release hash, but also the debug hash! I spent one day to find debug key, but it actually was near the release key (downside the console output)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that i registered app and enabled google signin on Firebase console but I was testing with the debug version of app which has slightly different package name (same name but ended with .debug) so it was not working because the debug app is not yet registered. so additionally to my release app i also added the debug app to the firebase project for the app and it generated it's own google-services.json which i download and set to src/debug/google-services.json.

I believe this might be useful to some one else.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the solution was:

1.In tab Gradle -> Double click signingReport -> get the SHA-1.

2.Copy this generated SHA-1 from Android Studio, then paste to Firebase -> Project Setting -> General Setting -> SHA FingerPrint.

3.In Project settings firebase Download file google-service.json

4.Add file google-service.json in project and rebuild.