# App not authorized to use Firebase Authentication but working fine with test phone

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm facing very strange behavior of Firebase. Everything is working fine when I first time upload my apk in play store. After few days when I update my apk. Now it show This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. check the screen shot. I read my answers on StackOverFlow. Almost all of them point that there is some problem in package name or in SHA-1 But in my case everything is perfect when I install app using android studio it's working fine but when I upload it on play store after this it does not work. And the strange thing is that when I enter any test phone it's working but not with the original phone number. I'm using real device. If there is any problem in package name or in SHA-1 then why it's working for test phone numbers ?

[image: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication]

**UPDATE**

I tried almost all the methods but no one is working for me.

I create sha-1 using this.

```
 keytool -list -v -keystore "key store path" -alias "key alias"
```

output is something like `96:A2:--------------------` I add this into firebase and generate new google_services.json file and place it into android project and upload apk to play store but when I try to run app it show me same error(app not authorized).

After this I try to create SHA-1 from android studio. using

> Gradle -> appName -> android -> signingReport

It show something like `B0:F7:-----------------------------` I add it into firebase console and generate google_servics.json file after uploading apk is not working.

After this I try

> tools -> firebase -> auth -> connect -> sync

This one is also not working.

And after this I try to add both SHA-1 in firebase console still not working.

Can you please let me know what can be problem ?

Comment: did you use seperate keystore for signing debug and release builds? if yes, do you have SHA1 of both added in firebase console?

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406#51360406)** out.

Comment: Application is working fine with test phone numbers but not with original phone numbers. If the problem is SHA-1 then it must not work with test phone numbers. There is another problem

Comment: I already try to added SHA-1 and update app but still same problem. How I update the SHA1 `tools->firebase->authentication->connect->sync` but still same issue

Comment: @AlexMamo Thing that is confusing me is that if there is SHA-1 problem then how it's working for test phone numbers ?

Comment: Did you figure that out? I delete all the sha-1 key and test phone number still work, which is very weird

Answer (score 0):

First copy your google-services.json file again to your project. Then you must be having your keystore for your release apk.
So in order to obtain the SHA1 of your release app.

- Go to your /bin in JDK directory.
- And run the following command in your cmd.

  ```
  keytool -list -v -keystore "key store path" -alias "key alias"
  ```

This command will give you all the required details of your release version. Copy the SHA1 string and add it to your firebase console.

You are good to go.