# Updating Firebase consoles platform SHA-1 key for release

Tags: android, firebase

Is it required to update Firebase consoles platform SHA-1 key for android release apk?
Does the key even change? 
Thanks

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406)** out.