# Android - Firebase Auth Failure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing a simple app.
I used Firebase Auth following below document.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui?authuser=0#top_of_page

In debug mode, it works fine.
In release mode, I create an Apk file, and install it directly, and it works fine too.

But when I released it into the PlayStore, and download it then it failed.

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            info("onActivityResult - ${user!!.email}")
            mPresenter.isAlreadyExistUser(user!!.email!!)
        } else {
            error("signIn failed - ${response!!.error}")  <-- Only when I downloaded it from playstore, it failed...
            response!!.error!!.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

W/System.err: com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Code: 12500, message: 12500: 
W/System.err:     at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.GoogleSignInHandler.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInHandler.java:106)
W/System.err:     at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.SingleSignInActivity.onActivityResult(SingleSignInActivity.java:121)
```

I tried to find the Error code 12500, but I cannot.
What happened?!

I executed "signinReport" in gradle, and I added the debug and release SHA-1 into the Firebase.

And then I downloaded the "google-services.json".

I am telling again, it works fine in debug apk and release apk.
But when I upload the working fine release apk into the PlayStore, it failed.

I really really don't know...

Comment: is that the same keyStore?

Comment: Check also **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406)** out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google verifies your signature, removes the signature, and processes the bundle to generate a base APK, configuration APK(s), and dynamic feature APKs (if applicable). And Google re-signs the APKs. So you have to add new SHA-1 sign for your app in Firebase console.
Open [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/)

Select **Release mangement**>**App signing** 
[image]

Use the provided **SHA-1** for firebase.

Comment: You mean, Should I copy the step 3's SHA-1 and paste it into the Firebase console? And then re-download "google-services.json" and re-generate signed apk?

Comment: No, you just got firebase console and select your project and the open your **Project Settings** and add this as _SHA certificate fingerprint_ and save it.

Comment: Really really Thank you!