# Unusual Firebase Google Sign-In Behavior

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I've been working on an Android project recently which required me to implement Google Sign-In feature in one the activity using Firebase. There's this unusual problem that I'm facing:

Whenever I build the program on my Android phone the google sign-in works fine. Enabling me to sign in easily. 
(I commit my code to Github)
Now when my mentor fetches the updated code from GitHub and builds the project on his phone, the Google Sign-In does not work i.e. he's unable to log in.

He gets the following error:

```
E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Code: 12500, message: 12500:
at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.GoogleSignInHandler.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInHandler.java:109)
at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.SingleSignInActivity.onActivityResult(SingleSignInActivity.java:128)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7317)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4436)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4484)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1743)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

However, when I send him the APK build on my system it works fine on his device.

What could be the possible reason for this and how do I solve this problem?

Comment: google-service.jason file is same on both side please check it

Comment: @YogeshBorhade Yes, I checked It's same. When I commit on GitHub, google-service.json also gets uploaded I guess

Comment: check both files are same .

Comment: @YogeshBorhade Are they suppose to be same or different??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sign In error 12500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632035/google-sign-in-error-12500)

Comment: @VikasTomar if you are using it for one app then credentials should be same ..

Comment: @YogeshBorhade Can you be more specific about what credentials you're talking about

Comment: @vikas tomar  as we are using google authentication so for that they provide use one google-service.json  file which should be same on every device , 
as you are uploading your code using github so may be there are chances that your file is not uploading properly.. so copy that file from your android studio and send it to another where code doesn't work  

Path for the file is :- Android Studio:-Project folder-> app-> google-service.json

if it does not work .. then check link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645607/android-firebase-auth-failure