# Android app SHA-1 authentication fail firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, sha1

My friend and I created an app and uploaded the APK on google play store. 
Some of our friends downloaded the app to try it, but they weren't able to register (using firebase number and/or email login). The error code says there's a problem with the SHA-1.
So we disabled the app on google store, and when I launch the app now (already installed from play store) it works perfectly! 
So I think that when the app is activated on the store, we have problems! 
Any idea?

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406)** out.

Comment: use app bundles. Your apks will also be very small compared to what you have now.

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Otto, You are getting this problem because your authentication is not well set. You happen to have no issues since you are using a debug version with a debug SHA-1 key, you should generate a new key for the release version and upload it on firebase. The SHA-1 key during debug mode is different from the release mode.

Answer (score 1):

There are different keys used for building your app, debug key and release key. The app you have installed on you phone is I think uses debug key which you have already registered with firebase, for you play store app to work you must also register release key you used to publish the app at play store (if you have used you own key at play store use that one or use a key that provided by google play store for signing the app).

Hope it helps.