# How to correct " com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: "

Tags: android, firebase

By following the steps to be completed.
But -> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:

**First, get your SHA-1 debug key :**

1. Click on Gradle (From Right Side Panel, you will see Gradle Bar)
2. Click on Tasks
3. Click on Android
4. Double Click on signingReport (You will get SHA-1 and MD5)

[image]

**Add new credentials to API Console :**

1. Go here https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
2. Create new OAuth Client ID
3. Name : Android client (for debug) (example)
4. Signing-certificate fingerprint : Copy paste you SHA-1 debug key
5. Put your package name then saved

[image]

**Add your key to your Firebase project :**

1. Go to Project settings -> SHA certificate fingerprints -> Add SHA-1
   key of debug app.
2. Then you can update your google-services.json file in your Android
   project.

[image]

**For end add web_client_id in your activity Login :**

[image]
[image]

**And add adress support :**

[image]

Comment: Try this link and configure your Project https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Comment: This is not android

Comment: If you had clicked on the configure your Project button you would know that you can Chose for what you want to configure

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406)** out.

Comment: That ok, it's work.