# How to fix "com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Code: 16, message: 16: "?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to authenticate my users using firebase authentication, but this error pops up.

I've already added the SHA1, but it still doesn't work.

> E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
>       com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Code: 16, message: 16: 
>           at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.GoogleSignInHandler.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInHandler.java:110)
>           at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.SingleSignInActivity.onActivityResult(SingleSignInActivity.java:128)
>           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406)** out.

Comment: Did you download the json file before or after you added the sha1?