# change SHA-1 in publish application google play.. with firebase integrations

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-services, sha1

i have problem that i dont know how to solve!!
i try to fix it almost a week.

i have application in google play, and i try to do google sign in authentication.

the problem is in the SHA-1.

when i use the keytool command on the keystore file to get SHA-1 relese i get something that start with 28.

when i do intagretion in firebase to link to Google Play,
it take another SHA-1 that start with B0, like the image below:

[image]

there is anyway to change the SHA-1 in the google play application? to solve this?

in the app folder i have the file google-service.json and i put the correct SHA-1, the one who start with 28, but it didnt help, when i do line its still take the SHA-1 who start with B0..

i will be thankfull for any help!

thanks!

**EDIT**
i want to make google sign in and get ApiExeption 10. this is because the SHA-1.
i want to change in the console play like the image below:
[image]

with what i read in some other posts, i see that i cant do it.

there another way still make google sign in with my application?
i have both 28 and B0 in firebase, google-service.json and google devloper API.

maybe i dont know which one i need to put in this code:

```
// Configure Google Sign In
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(*28 or B0?????????*)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
```

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10)** out.

Answer (score 0):

This works well for getting SHA-1

1. click to Gradle
2. click to root project name
3. click to Tasks
4. click to android
5. click right on signingReport

Your SHA-1 is ready.
This SHA-1 is for debuging version you can change Build Variants to release and try.

[image]