# Firebase sign-in with Google failed in release apk

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My app makes use of Firebase Realtime Database and Sign-In with Google authentication. In the test version of the app, everything ran smoothly. However, the sign in fails in the release version. I tried running the `signingReport` to get a different SHA-1, but it's the same key. I have `minifiyEnabled "false"` in my release version as someone suggested proguard might be interfering with some files. I have re-downloaded the `google-services.json` file too.

EDIT 1
I don't intend to publish the app on Google Play store. I just want to share the `.apk` itself with the users, could that be causing problems?

I don't know which files or code do I attach for reference.

Comment: did you add sha 1 key for Keystore inside your project in firebase console

Comment: Yes Biro Nadar, it's the same key as before the release. Thus, the console did not update when I added the Fingerprint.

Comment: you need SHA-256 too

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I just updated the SHA-256 from my `signingReport` into the Firebase console. Still no luck. If I run the app from Android Studio by connecting the device, it works properly.

Comment: I think this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406)** might help.

Comment: @VBDane you can show a toast for the error message in the error call back, to know what is the actual problem, if the problem with sha key the message will say that this app is not authorized to use firebase authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to solve this, it might help a newbie like me in the future.

I was entering the SHA-1 Key of the debug version of the app and not the release version. My app's release certificate's `keystore` wasn't added in the signing configurations and thus my signing configuration yielded the keys for the debug version instead of the release version . Here is how to solve it.

**Step 1**
Generate the release version of the signed apk and store the keystore (`.jks` file).

**Step 2**
Go to Project Structures on Android Studio (`Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S`). On the left pane of the Project Structures window, select Modules. Click on `SigningConfigs`. Press on the `Add Signing Config` button (`Alt+Insert`) and enter 'release' as the name of the config.

Link the `.jks` file we stored before and add the information about it inn the window and save it. Sync the project with `gradle` files.

**Step 3**
Open the `gradle` pane and select `SigningConfigs`. In the `gradle` console, you should have multiple certificate keys. The one with the version "`release`" is the one you must copy and paste in your Firebase Console.