# Google signin ,signup integration working in debug application, but not working in released apk

Tags: android, firebase

In my application google integration sign in and signup working in the debug version, whereas in signed APK it's not working. Whenever I log in to the RELEASED apk through google sign in or signup it shows a firebase error like this,

> E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
> "
> "message": "Requests from this Android client application com.package.com are blocked.",
> "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Comment: It's most likely because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406).

Answer (score 0):

Removing and connecting your app from Firebase will do the job. Remove the current apk, delete the *google services.json* file from the project, connect to Firebase again and also input your release keystore's **SHA1** key into the Firebase console (**Project Settings**).

Hope it works out!