# Which SHA-1 (debug or release) need to be added to a firebase android project

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

I've recently started new android firebase project and added my debug SHA-1 key I generated in android studio. I grabbed config `.json` file and started working in the app. Particular are of interest for this was google sign in.

Everything worked fine locally, so I created signed build (using signing keys managed by google play console and my upload key). I published build to internal testing. When I downloaded the app through play store, my google sign in was no longer working, so I assumed it is because I need to add SHA-1 for production / release build?

I added my `App signing key certificate` SHA-1 from google play console to firebase and downloaded new config json file. Now, google sign in doesn't work in debug nor in release and I am very confused.

Which SHA-1 keys need to be added to firebase? I have `Debug`, `App signing key certificate` (from google play console) and `Upload key certificate` (from google play console)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't add the **Release** SHA-1 Key in firebase. You need to add both. The debug key for developing and the release key is for when the app is released.

The debug and release SHA-1 key are different.

Here someone explains how to get the release key. [https://medium.com/fabcoding/how-to-obtain-sha1-keys-for-debug-and-release-android-studio-mac-34ff3703470b#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20enabled%20App,ll%20see%20you%20release%20SHA1](https://medium.com/fabcoding/how-to-obtain-sha1-keys-for-debug-and-release-android-studio-mac-34ff3703470b#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20enabled%20App,ll%20see%20you%20release%20SHA1).

Answer (score 1):

Add both debug and release SHA-1 to the project in firebase console. Then it will work for both; if you install app directly from android studio or
download from Google Play Store.
[image]