# Firebase - code 10 error google sign in. My friend who also have same project can't login, but I can

Tags: java, android, firebase

That's the problem of google logging in (code 10). On my virtual device I am able to log in, but my friend who have same project can't. His attempt produce exception below. We added debug sha-1, google sign in is enabled in firebase, (as I said from my computer I am able to use google sign in)

````
W/System.err: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.0.0:9)
        at me.jomi.androidapp.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:94)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7276)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)```
````

Comment: I think this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406)** might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link below was helpful, debug sha-1 means that you're able to debug your application if you apply it in firebase. If you want to authenticate other users, from other phones, you need more keys like release key, and google play key. So my friend also developer had to generate sha-1 debug key, and apply it in firebase too. My last question is which input data is generated to create sha-1 key?
[Firebase UI authentication with google fails with message (code:10 message:10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406)