# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, sha1, google-signin

> I'm trying to make google login with flutter app, and I got this error.
> I've already get and put SHA-1 key to OAuth and Firebase and set google-services.json file under app directory.
> But I still got same problem.

```
 E/flutter (12401): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
E/flutter (12401): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (12401): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)
E/flutter (12401): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12401): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:356:43)
E/flutter (12401): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12401): #3      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:235:30)
E/flutter (12401): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12401): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart)
E/flutter (12401): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12401):
```

> This is how I set.

[GCP OAuth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMy8Y.png)

[Firebase setting - I filled all blanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbbKr.png)

> and I don't know which `clientId` has to be on this area.

[which `clientId` has to be on this area?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puT5Y.png)

[I got 4 `clientId` because I already used google `clientId` to make `django` web login with google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmbvg.png)

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406) will help.

Comment: thank you let me try this way. Then I need to get all of 3 sha-1 keys and set on my firebase right?

Comment: Yes, all three keys are needed.

Comment: I'm running this app only with debug mode. It doesn't metter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 :
Add this dependency into your pubsec file

```
firebase: ^9.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.2.1
  firebase_database: ^7.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.2.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.3
```

Step : 2
Create a new dart file and paste this code

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class FirebaseService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<String?> signInwithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
          await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
          await googleSignInAccount!.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      );
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
      throw e;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signOutFromGoogle() async{
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    await _auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Step 3:
call sign in with google function:

Enable Google sign in Firebase
Add your SHA 1 key into Firebase Project

Comment: Thank you I tried this way. but I still got same issue. I post my code under answer. please check this.

Comment: I solved this problem with your code. I did flutter clean and then It worked