# on android Java, I am using firebase auth and UI

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I was working fine for the last 1 year, but now if I logging with an id that is logged in on some other device then it gives me the following error

A sign-in error occurred.
com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Error when saving credential.
at com.firebase.ui.auth.viewmodel.smartlock.SmartLockHandler.lambda$saveCredentials$0$SmartLockHandler(SmartLockHandler.java:97)
at com.firebase.ui.auth.viewmodel.smartlock.-$$Lambda$SmartLockHandler$pN6hZnWoFDaT_06xqjJRcsW8NkU.onComplete(Unknown Source:2)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:4)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: Cannot find an eligible account.
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:4)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zap.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:2)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zar.onComplete(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:6)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:177)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:136)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzo.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.0.0:6)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzp.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.0.0:4)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzu.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.0.0:9)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzc.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@@19.0.0:13)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1154)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406)?

Comment: check this first [ask]