# Android Google Login Working on Release signed Version But not Working On Release .aab file

Tags: firebase-authentication

I am getting the issue in .aab file only that google login is not working but in apk it is working properly.I am stucked from past 1 Week.I checked SHA-1 keys properly.i give both release and debug SHA-1 keys in firebase console and I already check those keys are inserted on google cloud console also.After I Created Released .aab version I checked on Browser Stack by installing .aab file but it always says Api Exception Error 10 .But when I try released signed apk it working good why this was happening please help me friends.

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406) might help.

Comment: But i am Not using firebase here Directly I am using Google Console I also added playconsole release signing key to google cloud console also they why .aab login not working but apk login is working

Comment: @VamsiReddy I'm facing the same issue and May I know how did you solved your issue.