# How to configure Firebase Auth on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-play-services

I have two variants of my build - **production** and **debug**.

Production with package: `com.mypackage`

Debug with package: `com.mypackage.debug`

I've created two different projects on Firebase. One for production and second for debug.
First project has package for production build type and second project for debug build type.

I've created signed build type and released my app for internal testers via Play Console.

I've added debug SHA1 key to my debug project on Firebase and I"ve added production SHA1, debug SHA1 and SHA1 from Play Console (App integrity) to my production Firebase project

Everything works fine, I can fetch and upload data to my each single type of database but authetication doesn't work.

User can autheticate via email or Google account.
When he/she tries to do that via Google account it returns error code `10`.
When he/she tries to do that via email app stops on  `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` account is created but users need to reopen the app and then he or she is registered.

I have folder for main/debug/release build type where I've added correct google-services.json

What is wrong? What is missing?
I will be grateful for any help because I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Most likely this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406) will help.

Comment: I saw that question before and I did all the things listed there.

When it comes to my problem I had to change requestIdToken
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).reguestIdToken(
token for debug or production version from gogole-services.json
)

Comment: Hi @Wafi_ck, could you clarify, were you able to solve your problem by fixing a typo?