# Firebase AuthUi error "Code:10, message:10". [No Google Play Option]

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Firebase AuthUi Google Sign In Code:10, message:10:

I use firebase auth-ui to sign in with google.
I followed the Google Codelabs tutorial (which was updated 15 September 2021) but no Login method is working.

[Google firebase Login Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-login)

it toasts

`Code:10, message:10:`

**Some Highlights to note**

1. I have this dependency

`implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:5.0.0'`

2. I have added SHA 1 and SHA 256 to my Firebase console
3. The only Login methods available are
   a. Email
   b. Google
4. This app is not going into Google Play store
5. There is no Google Play Login option
6. I'm not connecting my app to the PlayStore.
7. I have re-downloaded google-services.json file.
8. I read this thread
   [Firebase UI authentication with google fails with message (code:10 message:10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10)
   But the solution requires Google-play-console. As I said, this is a tutorial project and having an account on play console requires $25 - I shouldn't be paying $25 to test tutorial codes.

Comment: May we see some of the code you're using? The link you've provided with the solution requiring Play Console is for Apps that are already on the Play Store, and they state as much: "The problem started when I downloaded the app from the Play Store, the authentication was working perfectly when I was running the app in debug mode". So the issue you're facing is different

Comment: I had to reference that stack overflow thread because admin had tagged my question as duplicate

Comment: The code is exactly as seen in the 'Google Tutorial" page I referenced - I added nothing new.

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't realized the question had been flagged before

Answer (score 1):

I finally Solved the issue with these steps:

1. I followed the Firebase doc
   [Easily add sign-in to your Android app with FirebaseUI ][1]
2. I grant permissions for network

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
Step 5: Worki
```

3. I downloaded a newer google-services.json file
4. I rebuild the project

[1][https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui]