# API Exception 10 - Google sign in

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm making an app and I have implemented the Google sign in withe firebase feature. But for some reason when the `onActicityForResult()` or `ActivityResultLauncher()` is being called, i'm getting `API EXCEPTION 10`. I tried to add the correct SHA1 key to firebase and on my Google cloud console. I read a lot of questions here on SO but none of them helped me.

**LoginActivity onActivityForResult() is replaced from Activity Result Launcher:**

```
​public​ ​class​ ​LoginActivity​ ​extends​ ​AppCompatActivity​ { 
 
​    ​LoadingDialog​ progressDialog; 
​    ​public​ ​static​ ​String​ ​TAG​ ​=​ ​"​GoogleActivity: ​"​; 
​    ​public​ ​static​ ​int​ ​RC_SIGN_IN​ ​=​ ​9001​; 
​    ​GoogleSignInClient​ mGoogleSignInClient; 
​    ​FirebaseAuth​ mAuth ​=​ ​FirebaseAuth​.​getInstance(); 
 
​    ​ActivityResultLauncher<​Intent​>​ someActivityResultLauncher ​=​ ​registerForActivityResult​( 
​            ​new​ ​ActivityResultContracts​.​StartActivityForResult​(), 
​            new ActivityResultCallback​<​ActivityResult​>​() { 
​                ​@Override 
​                ​public​ ​void​ onActivityResult(​ActivityResult​ result) { 
​                    ​if​ (result​.​getResultCode() ​==​ ​Activity​.​RESULT_OK​ ​||​ result​.​getResultCode() ​==​ ​RC_SIGN_IN​) { 
 
​                        ​Intent​ data ​=​ result​.​getData(); 
​                        ​Task<​GoogleSignInAccount​>​ task ​=​ ​GoogleSignIn​.​getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data); 
 
​                        ​try​ { 
​                            ​//​ Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase 
​                            ​GoogleSignInAccount​ account ​=​ task​.​getResult(​ApiException​.​class); 
​                            ​Log​.​d(​TAG​, ​"​firebaseAuthWithGoogle:​"​ ​+​ account​.​getId()); 
​                            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account​.​getIdToken()); 
​                        } ​catch​ (​ApiException​ e) { 
​                            progressDialog​.​hide(); 
​                            ​new​ ​AlertDialog​.​Builder​(​LoginActivity​.​this​) 
​                                    .setTitle(​"​Error​"​) 
​                                    .setMessage(e​.​getLocalizedMessage()) 
​                                    .setPositiveButton(​"​OK​"​, (dialog, which) ​-​>​ dialog​.​dismiss()) 
​                                    .show(); 
​                        } 
​                    }​else​ { 
​                        ​Toast​.​makeText(​LoginActivity​.​this​, ​"​Error​"​, ​Toast​.​LENGTH_SHORT​)​.​show(); 
​                    } 
​                } 
​            }); 
 
 
​    ​void​ ​googleSignIn​() { 
​        ​Intent​ signInIntent ​=​ mGoogleSignInClient​.​getSignInIntent(); 
​        someActivityResultLauncher​.​launch(signInIntent); 
​        ​//​startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN); 
​    } 
 
​    ​void​ ​singIn​(​String​ ​email​, ​String​ ​password​) { 
 
​        ​//​ show progress dialog 
​        progressDialog​.​show(); 
 
​        mAuth​.​signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)​.​addOnSuccessListener(authResult ​-​>​ { 
​            progressDialog​.​hide(); 
​            finish(); 
​            startActivity(​new​ ​Intent​(​LoginActivity​.​this​, ​HomeActivity​.​class)); 
​            ​CustomIntent​.​customType(​LoginActivity​.​this​, ​"​left-to-right​"​); 
​            ​HomeActivity​.​anonymous ​=​ ​false​; 
​        })​.​addOnFailureListener(e ​-​>​ { 
​            progressDialog​.​hide(); 
​            ​new​ ​AlertDialog​.​Builder​(​LoginActivity​.​this​) 
​                    .setTitle(​"​Whoops!​"​) 
​                    .setMessage(e​.​getMessage()) 
​                    .setPositiveButton(​"​Okay​"​, (dialog, which) ​-​>​ dialog​.​dismiss())​.​show(); 
​        }); 
 
​    } 
 
​    ​@Override 
​    ​public​ ​void​ ​onBackPressed​() { 
​        ​super​.​onBackPressed(); 
​        finish(); 
​        ​CustomIntent​.​customType(​LoginActivity​.​this​, ​"​right-to-left​"​); 
​    } 
 
​    ​@Override 
​    ​protected​ ​void​ ​onCreate​(​Bundle​ ​savedInstanceState​) { 
​        ​super​.​onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
​        setContentView(​R​.​layout​.​activity_login); 
 
​        progressDialog ​=​ ​LoadingDialog​.​Companion​.​get(​LoginActivity​.​this​); 
 
​        ​EditText​ email ​=​ findViewById(​R​.​id​.​email_login); 
​        ​EditText​ password ​=​ findViewById(​R​.​id​.​password_login); 
​        ​Button​ submit ​=​ findViewById(​R​.​id​.​submit_login); 
​        ​TextView​ resetPasswordTV ​=​ findViewById(​R​.​id​.​textView6); 
​        ​TextView​ register ​=​ findViewById(​R​.​id​.​register_login); 
​        ​SignInButton​ googleSignInBtn ​=​ findViewById(​R​.​id​.​signInButton); 
 
​        ​//​ Google sign config 
​        ​GoogleSignInOptions​ gso ​=​ ​new​ ​GoogleSignInOptions​.​Builder​(​GoogleSignInOptions​.​DEFAULT_SIGN_IN​) 
​                .requestIdToken(getString(​R​.​string​.​default_web_client_id)) 
​                .requestEmail() 
​                .build(); 
 
​        mGoogleSignInClient ​=​ ​GoogleSignIn​.​getClient(​this​, gso); 
 
​        googleSignInBtn​.​setOnClickListener(view ​-​>​ { 
​            progressDialog​.​show(); 
​            googleSignIn(); 
​        }); 
 
​        resetPasswordTV​.​setOnClickListener(view ​-​>​ { 
 
​            ​AlertDialog​.​Builder​ dialog ​=​ ​new​ ​AlertDialog​.​Builder​(​LoginActivity​.​this​) 
​                    .setTitle(​"​Reset your password​"​); 
​            ​final​ ​EditText​ email_et ​=​ ​new​ ​EditText​(​LoginActivity​.​this​); 
​            email_et​.​setInputType(​InputType​.​TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME​); 
​            email_et​.​setHint(​"​Enter your email​"​); 
​            dialog​.​setView(email_et); 
​            dialog​.​setPositiveButton(​"​OK​"​, (dialogInterface, i) ​-​>​ { 
 
​                ​if​ (​!​email_et​.​getText()​.​toString()​.​isEmpty()) { 
​                    sendResetPasswordLink(email_et​.​getText()​.​toString()); 
​                } 
 
 
​            })​.​setNegativeButton(​"​Cancel​"​, (dialogInterface, i) ​-​>​ { 
​                dialogInterface​.​dismiss(); 
​            })​.​show(); 
 
​            ​FrameLayout​.​LayoutParams​ params ​=​ ​new​ ​FrameLayout​.​LayoutParams​(​550​, ​FrameLayout​.​LayoutParams​.​WRAP_CONTENT​); 
​            params​.​setMargins(​50​, ​6​, ​30​, ​6​); 
​            email_et​.​setLayoutParams(params); 
​        }); 
 
​        register​.​setOnClickListener(v ​-​>​ { 
​            finish(); 
​            startActivity(​new​ ​Intent​(​LoginActivity​.​this​, ​RegisterActivity​.​class)); 
​            ​CustomIntent​.​customType(​LoginActivity​.​this​, ​"​fadein-to-fadeout​"​); 
​        }); 
 
​        submit​.​setOnClickListener(v ​-​>​ { 
​            ​if​ (email​.​getText()​.​toString()​.​isEmpty() ​||​ password​.​getText()​.​toString()​.​isEmpty()) { 
​                ​new​ ​AlertDialog​.​Builder​(​LoginActivity​.​this​) 
​                        .setTitle(​"​Whoops!​"​) 
​                        .setMessage(​"​All fields are required​"​) 
​                        .setPositiveButton(​"​OK​"​, (dialog, which) ​-​>​ dialog​.​dismiss())​.​show(); 
​            } ​else​ { 
​                singIn(email​.​getText()​.​toString(), password​.​getText()​.​toString()); 
​            } 
​        }); 
 
​    } 
 
​    ​private​ ​void​ ​sendResetPasswordLink​(​String​ ​email​) { 
 
​        progressDialog​.​show(); 
 
​        mAuth​.​sendPasswordResetEmail(email)​.​addOnSuccessListener(task ​-​>​ { 
 
​            progressDialog​.​hide(); 
 
​            ​new​ ​AlertDialog​.​Builder​(​LoginActivity​.​this​) 
​                    .setIcon(​R​.​drawable​.​success_icon) 
​                    .setTitle(​"​Email send​"​) 
​                    .setMessage(​"​Reset password link has been send on this email address ​\n​"​ ​+​ email) 
​                    .setPositiveButton(​"​OK​"​, (dialog, which) ​-​>​ dialog​.​dismiss())​.​show(); 
 
​        })​.​addOnFailureListener(e ​-​>​ { 
 
​            progressDialog​.​hide(); 
 
​            ​new​ ​AlertDialog​.​Builder​(​LoginActivity​.​this​) 
​                    .setIcon(​R​.​drawable​.​error_icon) 
​                    .setTitle(​"​Error​"​) 
​                    .setMessage(e​.​getLocalizedMessage()) 
​                    .setPositiveButton(​"​OK​"​, (dialog, which) ​-​>​ dialog​.​dismiss())​.​show(); 
​        }); 
​    } 
 
​    ​private​ ​void​ ​firebaseAuthWithGoogle​(​String​ ​idToken​) { 
​        ​AuthCredential​ credential ​=​ ​GoogleAuthProvider​.​getCredential(idToken, ​null​); 
​        mAuth​.​signInWithCredential(credential) 
​                .addOnCompleteListener(​this​, task ​-​>​ { 
​                    ​if​ (task​.​isSuccessful()) { 
​                        ​//​ Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information 
​                        ​Log​.​d(​TAG​, ​"​signInWithCredential:success​"​); 
​                        ​FirebaseUser​ user ​=​ mAuth​.​getCurrentUser(); 
​                        updateUI(user, ​null​); 
​                    } ​else​ { 
​                        ​//​ If sign in fails, display a message to the user. 
​                        updateUI(​null​, task​.​getException()); 
 
​                    } 
​                }); 
​    } 
 
​    ​private​ ​void​ ​updateUI​(​FirebaseUser​ ​user​, ​Exception​ ​errorMsg​) { 
​        progressDialog​.​hide(); 
 
​        ​if​ (user ​!=​ ​null​) { 
 
​            ​DatabaseReference​ usersRef ​=​ ​FirebaseDatabase​.​getInstance()​.​getReference(​"​users​"​); 
 
​            usersRef​.​addListenerForSingleValueEvent(​new​ ​ValueEventListener​() { 
​                ​@Override 
​                ​public​ ​void​ ​onDataChange​(​@NonNull​ ​DataSnapshot​ ​snapshot​) { 
​                    ​if​ (​!​snapshot​.​child(user​.​getUid())​.​exists()) { 
​                        usersRef​.​child(user​.​getUid())​.​child(​"​id​"​)​.​setValue(user​.​getUid()); 
​                        usersRef​.​child(user​.​getUid())​.​child(​"​name​"​)​.​setValue(user​.​getDisplayName()); 
​                        usersRef​.​child(user​.​getUid())​.​child(​"​email​"​)​.​setValue(user​.​getEmail()); 
​                        usersRef​.​child(user​.​getUid())​.​child(​"​profileImgUrl​"​)​.​setValue(user​.​getPhotoUrl()); 
​                    } 
​                } 
 
​                ​@Override 
​                ​public​ ​void​ ​onCancelled​(​@NonNull​ ​DatabaseError​ ​error​) { 
​                    ​Toast​.​makeText(​LoginActivity​.​this​, ​"​Error: ​"​ ​+​ error​.​getMessage(), ​Toast​.​LENGTH_SHORT​)​.​show(); 
​                } 
​            }); 
 
​            finish(); 
​            startActivity(​new​ ​Intent​(​LoginActivity​.​this​, ​HomeActivity​.​class)); 
​            ​CustomIntent​.​customType(​LoginActivity​.​this​, ​"​left-to-right​"​); 
 
​            ​Toast​.​makeText(​LoginActivity​.​this​, ​"​Signed in as ​"​ ​+​ user​.​getDisplayName(), ​Toast​.​LENGTH_SHORT​)​.​show(); 
 
​        } ​else​ { 
​            ​new​ ​AlertDialog​.​Builder​(​LoginActivity​.​this​) 
​                    .setTitle(​"​Error​"​) 
​                    .setMessage(errorMsg​.​getLocalizedMessage()) 
​                    .setPositiveButton(​"​OK​"​, (dialog, which) ​-​>​ dialog​.​dismiss()) 
​                    .show(); 
​        } 
​        progressDialog​.​hide(); 
​    } 
 
​}
```

Comment: @Alex Mamo What did you mean?

Comment: It's most likely because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406). Sorry, I forgot to add the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by going Google play console -> MyApp -> Set-up -> Signing and adding the SHA1 key to firebase console