# PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null) - Even though SHA1 and SHA256 has bee registers

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin

I'm trying to implement google sign in, in my app, and i'm getting this error when im running-

Code-

```
final GoogleSignInAccount? acc= GoogleSignIn().signIn();
```

Error-

```
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
```

Upon digging deeper into this, I've come to know that this happens when the firebase project has not bbeen signed with a SHA1 and ShA256 fingerprint. However, I had already signed it with an SHA1 print. Then I also put in the SHA256 and redownloaded the `google-services.json` and it still doesn't work-

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please re download google-service.json file again and replace existing one and try again

Comment: Have you added support email?

Comment: Um, no, I haven't added a support email. Ok! I'll try re-downloading it. I think firebase is taking time to add the changes into the google-service.json

Comment: Nvm, still doesn't work

Comment: I have had simillar issues in past, It could be either because you are using different signing key or your package name , I think com.example does not work. You could try changing your package name something other than example

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406) will help.