# android Firebase not working in release builds

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

i created a key and generated a signed apk with the key created.

i used "Generate Signed apk" in android studio

then i used the keytool command to extract the SHA1 fingerprint and added to the firebase console in my app project settings

but still firebase does not work in release builds but works fine in debug variant.

```
android {
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('C:\\folder\\signkey.jks')
        keyAlias 'key0'
        storePassword ********
        keyPassword ********
    }
}
compileSdk 31

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled = true
        shrinkResources = true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

i checked gradle and the signing config is correctly configured and i tried generating another key but also didnt work

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51360406/5246885)?

Comment: i visited these links before and from what i understood i did the exact same steps and made sure to use the SHA from key i deployed the release apk with, am i missing something?