# Android App can't Read or Write to Firestore after Upload (Release)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app is user-based, and so each user has his data saved in the app's `Firestore Database`.
When the app is in debug mode (installed on my device by `Android Studio`), there's no problem reading and writing to `Firestore`.
The problem is, when the app is installed from the `Play Store` (So I guess this means it's in `release` mode), the app is no longer able to read and write to the `Firebase Database`.
All of the SHA1 and SHA256 are added to the `Firebase` app, including the debug keys, release keys, and update keys, while I got the last two from the `Play Console` (of the specific app), so probably the problem doesn't lie in these keys.

Here're my `Firestore` rules, if there's any chance that they're relevant:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid}{
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

If any other code pieces are needed, say the word and I'll add them.

What's the problem, then?
And how can I fix it?
Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you [checked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51360406/5246885) this out?

Comment: @AlexMamo I've read it now, and as I said, I have added all of these keys

Comment: Please share any error or log related to your issue.

Comment: @Osvaldo I will, how can I get them though? Which errors am I expecting? I'll try to see if there're any errors during the data loading from the firestore, however, authenticating itself works

Comment: As suggested [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#writing_rule), in the *Allow all* tab example, you should *NEVER* use your second match statement in production because it allows anyone to overwrite your entire database. You could be hitting quota limits: if you’re on the free plan, writes, reads and deletes are limited.
Take a look at this [authentication rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication). Please share any message that appears in the Firebase console.