# phone authentication is not working after publishing the app on playstore

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have released the app on the play store but the phone authentication is not working I have added the app signing sh1 key and upload sh1 key from play console to the firebase in the project but still it is not working.

Please guide me

it is thworing the toast app is not authrized to use firebase authentication.

Comment: If you're getting a code10 error message then this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406) will help.

Comment: no sir i am not getting this error it is saying that  app is not authrized to use firebase authentication.