# Firebase not workingin actual app made in UNITY

Tags: android, database, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

Firebase authentication working fine in simulation of the app/game in Unity but then won't work in actual build app? What might be the problem here? Btw the project is android based and data capturing wasn't required a SHA key or so I guess.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Most likely this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406) will help.