# Google Sign in gives me signInResult:failed code=10 after add SHA and web client

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

I'm integrating google login into my android app and it gives me the following error: signInResult:failed code=10 .
I have been consulting forums in search of the solution, but I already have the necessary SHA certificate fingerprints configured in firebase and the OAuth 2.0 web client that they indicate. I don't know how to make it work. Thanks.

I followed the google guide and I still have this problem. I have reviewed the whole issue of the fingerprints of the SHA certificate and the web client key. I have also completed the consent screen.
I have tested the code in the app in a test app, which I have registered in a different firebase project, and it works correctly. I don't know if I have to create a new project because the one I have is broken.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: It's most likely because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51360406/5246885).

Comment: Hello. That's what I thought, but I have it configured. What's more, I have different apps (flavors) in this android project, but I have them in another firebase project and it works for me. I had to separate the apps because I reached the limit and google forced me.
  I have done a test changing an app to the other project and updating the SHA and the web client and it works for me. I don't know why not in that project.

One last thing. Does it have to do with the fact that when I try to delete a SHA from some app in firebase I get an error?

Answer (score 0):

Important: For every SHA you use to sign your app when building, whether it's a debug build or a release build, Google creates a new OAuth 2.0 client ID. If you reach the limit of your project, no more will be created, so Google Sign In will return a signInResult:failed code=10.