# Google sign-in fails with sign_in_failed ApiException 10: error, Firebase project keeps detecting a duplicate SHA1/package name pair

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-signin

I have a Flutter project using Firebase Cloud Messaging. The application and Cloud Messaging run fine. I use Android for most of my development.

Recently I tried to use the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) Flutter package. I want to perform a Play Games sign-in, which is supported by the package (please note that, for now, I do not want to use other packages, such as `games_services` for Flutter, for various reasons).

Here is my sign-in code

```
GoogleSignInAccount? account = await GoogleSignIn.signIn(GoogleSignIn.games());
```

Unfortunately, I get a `PlatformException: sign_in_failed, ApiException: 10` when this line is executed.

In the Firebase Console, I have 2 projects registered:

- a development project, that has an Android application registered with my debug SHA1 fingerprint
- a production project, that has an Android application registered with my release (production) SHA1 fingerprint.

I obtained both fingerprints using `gradlew signingReport`.

Both projects use the same application package name.

For some reason, in the development project that I am currently doing my tests with (meaning I have a `google-services.json` file for that project in my code), I get a yellow warning sign saying the SHA1/package pair is already used in another project. But that's not the case: the other project has the release-mode SHA1.

Does the Firebase Console look elsewhere to determine if the SHA1/package name pair is unique? Like, in the Google Cloud or even the Play Console?

Comment: Did you see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51360406/5246885)?