# Google Sign in Not Working in Release build in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

I've encountered a perplexing issue with Google Sign-In functionality in my Android application. Surprisingly, Google Sign-In works seamlessly in the debug build but fails to function in the release build. Despite following the necessary steps, including configuring the SHA-1 fingerprint, verifying OAuth 2.0 Client IDs, and integrating the latest google-services.json file, the release build consistently faces Google Sign-In failures.

I've double-checked the ProGuard rules to ensure that the required classes and configurations for Google Sign-In are not obfuscated or stripped. The SHA-1 fingerprint is correctly added to the Google Cloud Console, and the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs are appropriately configured for both debug and release environments.

Interestingly, no errors or exceptions are logged during the Google Sign-In process in the release build. This issue only arises in the release variant, making it challenging to pinpoint the exact cause. I've tested it on real devices and checked for differences in configurations but to no avail.

Comment: Did you see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51360406/5246885)? Does it help?

Comment: And since you're using Jetpack Compose, perhaps this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).